# php timezone and time not match

Tags: php

i set time zone in php:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul");
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Istanbul');
```

then when i get the date time and time zone

```
date('Y-m-d H:i'); date_default_timezone_get();
```

that prints

```
2012-01-10 05:20 Europe/Istanbul
```

time zone is correct but time is wrong, 
any ideas, what would be the reason?
thanks!

Comment: When the timezone is unrecognized, the time usually appears in UTC. Is the time output you are getting the correct UTC representation of the time you wanted? If so, that at least gives you a clue that "Europe/Istanbul" is not recognized. FWIW, that timezone is recognized on all of the Debian, Ubuntu, and Solaris systems I've just checked.

Comment: Next time, put code in code blocks (4 spaces before each line). The editor toolbar is your friend.

Comment: Can you describe *how* the time is incorrect? Too late, too early... and by how many hours?

Comment: hi Pekka, time is 7 hours too early

Comment: Celada, no it is not correct UTC.

Comment: Just to make sure: is your server's time and timezone set correctly?

Comment: @deceze, it is, but time i got is not the same as the the one on the server either

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP is >= 5.2.0 then you can use the DateTime object:

```
$my_timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$far_away_timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul');

$dt = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $my_timezone);
$dt->setTimezone($far_away_timezone);

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Hope it helps.